# Magento 2 | Event for success page

Tags: magento2, event-observer, order-success-page

what is the correct event which should fire when a customer ordered something and is being redirected to the success page. After the redirect to the success page the event should fire.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use following event for success page.

```
checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
```

To get Order id

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        $orderId = $orderIds[0];

    }
```

Event Fire at

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage;

class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage
{
    /**
     * Order success action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
        if (!$this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\SuccessValidator::class)->isValid()) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
        }
        $session->clearQuote();
        //@todo: Refactor it to match CQRS
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action',
            ['order_ids' => [$session->getLastOrderId()]]
        );
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there an event which fires AFTER the success page has been loaded?

Comment: @k33n it is firing before page loading. i updated the code kindly check that too.

Answer (score 1):

Use below event which trigger in success page

```
 checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
```

its uses in below controller

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage;

class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage
{
    /**
     * Order success action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
        if (!$this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\SuccessValidator::class)->isValid()) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
        }
        $session->clearQuote();
        //@todo: Refactor it to match CQRS
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action',
            ['order_ids' => [$session->getLastOrderId()]]
        );
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```